# CGAL partition self-intersecting polygon

Tags: c++, macos, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

To get the triangulation of a concave polygon, I use `CGAL::approx_convex_partition_2` on an input polygon, then I compute the `CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2` on each produced polygon.

Everything is fine, except that the CGAL partitioning functions **don't accept self-intersecting polygons**.

In a previous version of my program (without CGAL) I used [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) to get simple polygons from a self-intersecting one.

Is there a function or a code snippet in CGAL to get intersection points of a polygon and build new simple polygons from these points ?

Comment: I don't think there is a function cleaning the polygon for you but using an arrangement of its segments it should be quite straight-forward to detect self-intersection and fix them.

Comment: Thank you sloriot, I'll give a try at getting the intersections. It seems that there are some useful functions for this...